# #define not executing all arguments

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with a #define I have made. For some reason it is not checking all the arguments in the statement.

```
THROW_AND_LOG(Foo::Initialize() && Bar::Initialize() && FooBar::Initialize(), "Something() could not Initialize singletons.");
```

For some reason it is only initializes Foo and then exits the statement. It does not throw or log.

However

```
THROW_AND_LOG((Foo::Initialize() && Bar::Initialize() && FooBar::Initialize()), "Something() could not Initialize singletons.");
```

works fine for some reason. (Wrapped all the checks in brackets).

I am going to move everything on to its own seperate line to fix this as its not the best code in the first place. I am curious however of why it would not execute all statements.

Here is the define:

```
#define THROW_AND_LOG(x, message) if(!x) { throw std::runtime_error(message);              \
    LOG::v1::MessageSender messageSender("log");                                           \
    LOGGING_ERROR(messageSender,message);}
```

Comment: Why is this a macro?

Comment: I was logging errors and throwing and was told to make a macro. Is the problem with creating a unnecessary macro or should I not be logging and throwing? Perhaps only catch the log at the end?

Comment: @marsh: You need a macro for picking up `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. But separate concerns. Create a macro for just that, picking up that information. Use ordinary functions for the rest.

Comment: The logging system actually grabs all that info already. Though I did forget about it until you mentioned it.

Comment: _"was told to make a macro"_ By whom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the macro definition

```
#define THROW_AND_LOG(x, message) if(!x) { throw std::runtime_error(message);              \
    LOG::v1::MessageSender messageSender("log");                                           \
    LOGGING_ERROR(messageSender,message);}
```

the invocation

```
THROW_AND_LOG(Foo::Initialize() && Bar::Initialize() && FooBar::Initialize(), "Something() could not Initialize singletons.");
```

yields the condition

```
if(!Foo::Initialize() && Bar::Initialize() && FooBar::Initialize())
```

which is equivalent to

```
if((!Foo::Initialize()) && Bar::Initialize() && FooBar::Initialize())
```

---

A good fix is to replace the macro with a function:

```
void throw_and_log_if(
     const bool          condition,
     const Location&     location,
     const string&       message )
{
    LOG::v1::MessageSender messageSender( "log" );
    LOGGING_ERROR( messageSender, message ); }
    throw std::runtime_error( message );
}
```

where `Location` is some class representing file and line number, which you can pick up via the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros.

I took the liberty of fixing the bug causing logging to not be performed.

---

A short term easier fix is to use parenthesis around the `x` in the macro's condition.

If you choose that, then do remember to fix the bug in the macro.

Comment: Oh, they'll (the OP) have a hard time to figure out what's `Location` actually :-P. C'mon Chuck!

Answer (score 7):

After the macro expansion,

```
if(!x)
```

transforms to

```
if(!Foo::Initialize() && Bar::Initialize() && FooBar::Initialize())
```

`Foo::Initialize()` presumably returns `true`, so `!Foo::Initialize()` is `false` and other terms are not executed (not mentioning that their meaning has changed to the opposite).

Answer (score 6):

It's not expanding the way you think it is. You want `(!(x))` in your macro.